# Interpret Coefficeint as change in Percentage-point or Percentage

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients

Having carried out the regression below, I'm struggling to determine what the correct interpretation of the *predictor* variable would be.

Given that the dependent variable is binary, where 1=receiving a medicine and 0= not receiving a medicine. And the *predictor* variable is a measure of distance measured in km from a hospital.

Would the correct interpretation be that a 1km increase in distance from the hospital leads to a 2.26 percentage-point increase in the probability of receiving the medicine?

OR, a 1km increase in distance from the hospital leads to a 2.26% increase in the probability of receiving the medicine?

I'm trying to understand the difference between the two interpretations and which would be correct wrt to the regression?

[image]

Comment: Did you perform normal regression or logistic regression? If the output is binary, a normal regression is not the correct tool to use.

Comment: The regression was in fact the First stage of a Two Stage Least-Square computation. Even in that case would I have had to use another type of regression?

Comment: I dont know what you mean by two stage computation. However, if the predicted value is binary then you should you a Logit or a Probit regression - which predict the probabilty instead of the value.

Comment: If you're using 2SLS, what are your true variables? You can do 2SLS with binary outcomes, but I believe the predictors must also be binary. Were you told to use 2SLS here? Also, 0.226261 would be 22.61%.

Comment: Drawing a graph would help you think about this.

Comment: I should have clarified that this was essentially a linear probability model. I'm simply confused as to whether the interpretation should be that a 1km increase in the predictor variable leads to a 22.6% percentage increase or a percentage-point increase...